# Update collection in MongoDb via Apache Spark using Mongo-Hadoop connector

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, rdd

I would like to update a specific collection in MongoDb via Spark in Java.
I am using the [MongoDB Connector for Hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) to retrieve and save information from [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) to MongoDb in Java.

After following Sampo Niskanen's excellent [post regarding retrieving and saving collections to MongoDb via Spark,](http://codeforhire.com/2014/02/18/using-spark-with-mongodb/) I got stuck with updating collections.

[MongoOutputFormat.java](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/MongoOutputFormat.java) includes a constructor taking String[] updateKeys, which I am guessing is referring to a possible list of keys to compare on existing collections and perform an update.  However, using Spark's `saveAsNewApiHadoopFile()` method with parameter `MongoOutputFormat.class`, I am wondering how to use that update constructor.

```java
save.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///bogus", Object.class, Object.class, MongoOutputFormat.class, config);
```

Prior to this, [MongoUpdateWritable.java](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/io/MongoUpdateWritable.java) was being used to perform collection updates.  From examples I've seen on Hadoop, this is normally set on `mongo.job.output.value`, maybe like this in Spark:

```java
save.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///bogus", Object.class, MongoUpdateWritable.class, MongoOutputFormat.class, config);
```

However, I'm still wondering how to specify the update keys in `MongoUpdateWritable.java`.

Admittedly, as a hacky way, I've set the "_id" of the object as my document's KeyValue so that when a save is performed, the collection will overwrite the documents having the same KeyValue as `_id`.

```java
JavaPairRDD<BSONObject,?> analyticsResult; //JavaPairRdd of (mongoObject,result)
JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> save = analyticsResult.mapToPair(s -> {
    BSONObject o = (BSONObject) s._1;

    //for all keys, set _id to key:value_
    String id = "";
    for (String key : o.keySet()){
        id += key + ":" + (String) o.get(key) + "_";
    }
    o.put("_id", id);

    o.put("result", s._2);
    return new Tuple2<>(null, o);
});

save.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///bogus", Object.class, Object.class, MongoOutputFormat.class, config);
```

I would like to perform the mongodb collection update via Spark using `MongoOutputFormat` or `MongoUpdateWritable` or `Configuration`, ideally using the `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile()` method.  Is it possible? If not, is there any other way that does not involve specifically setting the _id to the key values I want to update on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried several combination of `config.set("mongo.job.output.value","....")` and several combination of

```scala
.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
        "file:///bogus",
        classOf[Any],
        classOf[Any],
        classOf[com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat[Any, Any]],
        mongo_config
      )
```

and none of them worked.

I made it to work by using `MongoUpdateWritable` class as output of my map method:

```scala
items.map(row => {
      val mongo_id = new ObjectId(row("id").toString)
      val query = new BasicBSONObject()
      query.append("_id", mongo_id)
      val update = new BasicBSONObject()

      update.append("$set", new BasicBSONObject().append("field_name", row("new_value")))
      val muw = new MongoUpdateWritable(query,update,false,true)
      (null, muw)
    })
     .saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
       "file:///bogus",
       classOf[Any],
       classOf[Any],
       classOf[com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat[Any, Any]],
       mongo_config
     )
```

The raw query executed in mongo is then something like this:

```
2014-11-09T13:32:11.609-0800 [conn438] update db.users query: { _id: ObjectId('5436edd3e4b051de6a505af9') } update: { $set: { value: 10 } } nMatched:1 nModified:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:24 3ms
```