# How to update multiple fields in mongo collection using spark and mongo Hadoop connector?

Tags: mongodb, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am using mongo hadoop connector to connect mongo with spark and scala.

I want to update (upsert) multiple values of mongo collection using mongo and spark.

I tried following--

```
val query = new BasicBSONObject()
query.append("customerId", customerId)

val update = new BasicBSONObject()
val bson = new BasicBSONObject()
bson.put("minimumUtilization", some value)
bson.put("maximumUtilization", some value)
bson.put("averageUtilization", some value)
bson.put("customerId", customerId)
```

Now how do I use above objects to update a collection using spark and mongo hadoop connector??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update collection in MongoDb via Apache Spark using Mongo-Hadoop connector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526717/update-collection-in-mongodb-via-apache-spark-using-mongo-hadoop-connector)

Answer (score 0):

see here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage

use MongoUpdateWritable.
create a RDD of MongoUpdateWritable(query,update,upsert,multiupdate,replace) then

```
updates.map(f =>(null,f)).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
      "file:///this-is-completely-unused",
      classOf[Object],
      classOf[MongoUpdateWritable],
      classOf[MongoOutputFormat[Object, MongoUpdateWritable]],
      outputConfig)
```